# Set up proxy for selenide?

Tags: java, maven, proxy, selenide

Is there any possibility to set up proxy for selenide library?

I start autotests from command line with maven comman:

```
mvn clean test [some params] site
```

It was possible to change maven setting to use proxy (in `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml`) so it can download dependencies.

But one of dependencies is [selenine](/questions/tagged/selenine) which requests `http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/` to check/download last version of chromedriver.exe. And here I've got an error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com

io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: java.net.UnknownHostException: chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:475)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:458)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.handleException(WebDriverManager.java:472)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:458)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:219)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverBinaryManager.setupBinaryPath(WebDriverBinaryManager.java:16)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:55)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.createDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:231)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverThreadLocalContainer.java:118)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverRunner.getAndCheckWebDriver(WebDriverRunner.java:136)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.navigateToAbsoluteUrl(Navigator.java:68)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.Navigator.open(Navigator.java:32)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:95)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open(Selenide.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a system property to set proxy for web driver manager:

```
System.setProperty("wdm.proxy", url);    // url as "http://host:port"
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyUser", url);
System.setProperty("wdm.proxyPass", url);
```

More info https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager#configuration